# Wireless mouse stops working, when in battery, for a couple of seconds now and then

Tags: wireless, mouse, battery, 13.10

I'm using a Logitech wireless mouse in Ubuntu 13.10 and, when in battery, it stops working every now and then!

It works specially when I write something. Right now, If I try to move my pointer (using the mouse), it won't work. I need to wait a couple of seconds. (The touchpad works fine)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem to be laptop-mode-tools.

I removed that and installed TLP instead. Everything is perfect now.